# Аннотации Doctrine для форм

Tags: doctrine2, аннотации

Посоветуйте пожалуйста как лучше создавать/строить формы на базе сущности, сгенерированной Доктриной.
Есть вариант ручками дописать в сущности @Annotation, но при регенерации все затрется.

среда - Zend Expressive + Doctrine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вы перегенерируете модель после внесения изменений в БД. Так делать не нужно.

Модель - первична. Вы работаете с моделью, напрямую работать с БД не нужно. Для поддержания в соответствии БД и модели существуют миграции. Например, пакет doctrine/migrations позволяет автоматизированно генерировать SQL-миграции на основе изменений в модели.

Т.е. общий процесс должен быть таков:

1. Создать/изменить модель
2. Написать или сгенерировать миграцию
3. Выполнить миграцию в БД.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html

Comment: Точно! Надо освоить миграции и работать только с моделью, я так понимаю, командами можно менять только таблицу в БД, не меняя модели?
Про миграции пока ничего не знаю. Очень полезный совет, спасибо!